# I need a unique Identifier for my domain controller in c#/UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, active-directory

I wrote an Application for a Intranet like experience in C# with UWP.
We want to give the App to our students, but we also want it to have an Administrator Tab, which should only be visible to our Admins. In order to accomplish that i need to Identify the domain the User is logged on.

My Idea was that anyone could create an Active Directory and name it like ours so I need a way to identify the domain ith something thats unique all over the World.

Is there a feature like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-5.0) for that.

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all
> computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such
> an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

The chance of getting a duplicate GUID is insanely low. See [Wikipedia UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for details

Comment: ty ill use that :D